# Mouse Position with respect to image in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to conform to the MVVM structure when getting the mouse position when it is over an image in a wpf application. The mouse position should be converted to a pixel location with respect to the image.

I have this working when Image_MouseMove is in ImagePositionView.xaml.cs, but I'm at a bit of a loss (even after trying to read other threads) as to how to achieve this using the MVVM structure.

I have added a reference to MVVMLight in hopes that this will make this task easier, but I have never used to before..

This is what I have so far:

View:

I have added these references based on what I have seen:

`xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`
`xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"`

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImagePixelLocation.View.ImagePositionView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImagePixelLocation"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="1000" Background="White">

   <Grid>
       <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center">
           <Grid Name="ColorImage">
               <Image x:Name="ImageOnDisplay" Source="{Binding ColourImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
           </Grid>
       </Viewbox>
   </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

ViewModelBase exposes INofityPropertyChanged and IDisposable

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace ImagePixelView.ViewModel
{
    class ImagePositionViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private WriteableBitmap colourBitmap = null;

        public ImageSource ColourImage
        {
            get
            {
                return this.colourBitmap;
            }
        }


        public ManualSelectionViewModel()
        {
            // Open image to writeablebitmap
            string path = @"C:\Some\Path\To\ColorImage.png";

            Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            var decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            BitmapSource source = decoder.Frames[0];

            int width = source.PixelWidth;
            int height = source.PixelHeight;
            int stride = source.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8 * width;
            byte[] data = new byte[stride * height];
            source.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);

            this.colourBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96.0, 96.0, source.Format, null);
            this.colourBitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), data, stride, 0);
        }


        private void Image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            BitmapSource bitmapImage = (BitmapSource)this.ColourImage;

            string xCoord = (e.GetPosition(ImageOnDisplay).X * bitmapImage.PixelWidth / ImageOnDisplay.ActualWidth).ToString();
            string yCoord = (e.GetPosition(ImageOnDisplay).Y * bitmapImage.PixelHeight / ImageOnDisplay.ActualHeight).ToString();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("mouse location is X:" + xCoord + ", Y:" + yCoord);
        }

    }
}
```

I guess the main thing is how do I get access to the view element `ImageOnDisplay` from within `ImagePositionViewModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this with a behaviour. First I declare an interface that my view model will implement:

```
public interface IMouseCaptureProxy
{
    event EventHandler Capture;
    event EventHandler Release;

    void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseCaptureArgs e);
    void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseCaptureArgs e);
    void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseCaptureArgs e);
}

public class MouseCaptureArgs
{
    public double X {get; set;}
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public bool LeftButton { get; set; }
    public bool RightButton { get; set; }
}
```

And here's a behaviour that uses it:

```
public class MouseCaptureBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProxyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Proxy",
        typeof(IMouseCaptureProxy),
        typeof(MouseCaptureBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnProxyChanged));

    public static void SetProxy(DependencyObject source, IMouseCaptureProxy value)
    {
        source.SetValue(ProxyProperty, value);
    }

    public static IMouseCaptureProxy GetProxy(DependencyObject source)
    {
        return (IMouseCaptureProxy)source.GetValue(ProxyProperty);
    }

    private static void OnProxyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldValue is IMouseCaptureProxy)
        {
            (e.OldValue as IMouseCaptureProxy).Capture -= OnCapture;
            (e.OldValue as IMouseCaptureProxy).Release -= OnRelease;
        }
        if (e.NewValue is IMouseCaptureProxy)
        {
            (e.NewValue as IMouseCaptureProxy).Capture += OnCapture;
            (e.NewValue as IMouseCaptureProxy).Release += OnRelease;
        }
    }

    static void OnCapture(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = sender as MouseCaptureBehavior;
        if (behavior != null)
            behavior.AssociatedObject.CaptureMouse();
    }

    static void OnRelease(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = sender as MouseCaptureBehavior;
        if (behavior != null)
            behavior.AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown += OnMouseDown;
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseMove += OnMouseMove;
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp += OnMouseUp;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown -= OnMouseDown;
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseMove -= OnMouseMove;
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp -= OnMouseUp;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var proxy = GetProxy(this);
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            var pos = e.GetPosition(this.AssociatedObject);
            var args = new MouseCaptureArgs {
                X = pos.X,
                Y = pos.Y,
                LeftButton = (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed),
                RightButton = (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            };
            proxy.OnMouseDown(this, args);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var proxy = GetProxy(this);
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            var pos = e.GetPosition(this.AssociatedObject);
            var args = new MouseCaptureArgs {
                X = pos.X,
                Y = pos.Y,
                LeftButton = (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed),
                RightButton = (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            };
            proxy.OnMouseMove(this, args);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var proxy = GetProxy(this);
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            var pos = e.GetPosition(this.AssociatedObject);
            var args = new MouseCaptureArgs
            {
                X = pos.X,
                Y = pos.Y,
                LeftButton = (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed),
                RightButton = (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            };
            proxy.OnMouseUp(this, args);
        }
    }

}
```

To use this behaviour you add it to the target UI element and bind to an object that implements the proxy interface. In this case I made the MainViewModel implement the interface so I just bind to that:

```
<!-- Canvas must have a background, even if it's Transparent -->
<Canvas Background="White" xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:MouseCaptureBehavior Proxy="{Binding}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The view model now needs to provide mouse handlers which the behaviour will call, it also needs to provide the Capture/Release events which the behaviour will respond to when raised by the view model:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMouseCaptureProxy
{
    public event EventHandler Capture;
    public event EventHandler Release;

    public void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseCaptureArgs e) {...}
    public void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseCaptureArgs e) {...}
    public void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseCaptureArgs e) {...}
}
```

UPDATE: It should be self-evident, but just in case not: the sender that you pass in to the Capture and Release events should be the same one you received via the MouseDown/Move/Up handlers. The event args passed to Capture/Receive aren't used and can be null.

Comment: Using of view types in the ViewModel is a violation of the MVVM pattern, that's specifically what the OP asked for to avoid.

Comment: @Tseng I'm not using any view types, go look at my code again.

Comment: Take a look at the MSDN and see in which assembly `MouseCaptureArgs` is defined

Comment: @Tseng I'm not using the .NET MouseCaptureArgs class in the view model, only in the behavior. Go look at my code again.

Comment: My bad. Still, suboptimal solution. Better to use attached properties instead, they can be directly bound via data binding (i.e. using a `Rect` or `Point`so) and avoid having a too specific implementation that depends on an interface tied to the behavior. Then you can bind any viewmodel to it, without having to reference/implement the interface. On more complex requirements, extending the `ImageView` via dependencies properties may be more suitable

Comment: Actually I do agree with you on that, however if you use events to trigger actions back in the view (as I do in this simple example with Capture/Release) then you wind up having to encapsulate them in wrappers regardless in order to get binding to work, at which point you're probably better off to formalize a more tightly-coupled interface.  It's essentially what you'd be doing with a service-based approach anyway. Still, to each their own.....

Comment: Thinking more about this....in real-world code you invariably wind up needing to implement down/move/up/capture/release anyway, particularly if you want to support in-process drag-n-drop or bounded selections etc. This would mean adding 5 separate bindings to every UI element that requires mouse interaction, even though the majority would typically require all 5 anyway. I'm totally open-minded to alternate/better ways of doing this, just having a difficult time justifying it in my head for mouse interactions which inevitably turn out more complicated than they initially appear.

Comment: 1 Dependency property & one command per action required. From the question it's not clear if mouse interaction is required at all

Comment: @Tseng MouseDown will be required as that action will get the pixel location. I'm actually having difficulty getting the UserControl to display in the MainWindow View. All it is doing is displaying the name of the associated viewmodel, so I'll have to get back to this answer once I've got it working.

Comment: Where would `IMouseCaptureProxy`, `MouseCaptureArgs` and `MouseCaptureBehavior` normally be stored in the project structure? In model, viewmodel, or some other location?

Comment: In MVVM you should always be able to create the view model independent of the view, so IMouseCaptureProxy and MouseCaptureArgs belong in the view model layer. MouseCaptureBehaviour, like all other behaviours, belongs in the view layer.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to get an idea of how this operates, but I'm still a bit lost on the last two steps, so I'll start with the Canvas, in particular how is it added to a particular UI element such as an Image? As for `Proxy = "{Binding}"` should that be `Binding ManualSelectionViewModel` if it implements the interface?

Comment: @Ayb4btu it's exactly the same, just replace the Canvas tag with `<Image Source="...etc...">`. And yes, the binding should be to whatever implements the interface.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Thanks. As you've probably noticed I'm pretty new to this stuff; I'm still unsure on the `Capture` and `Release` EventHandlers. How do they need to be set?

Comment: @Ayb4btu you don't set them, the behaviour automatically subscribes to them and you raise them as needed. If you mousedown on your image (say) and you want to start capturing the mouse then do a `Capture(sender, null)`, where `sender` is the one passed into your MouseDown handler. Same goes for mouseup where you would call `Release(sender, null)' to stop capturing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Loading image and display its xy coordinates with rgb values when mouse move on image using MVVM..
Hope this will be help full for some one..

ViewModel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Bitmap Img; 
    public ICommand OpenImg { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        OpenImg = new RelayCommand(openImg, (obj) => true);
    }       
    private void openImg(object obj = null)
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.Title = "Select a picture";
        op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp;*.tiff|" +
          "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
          "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
        if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            ImgPath = op.FileName;
            Img = new Bitmap(ImgPath);
        }
    }

    private string _ImgPath;
    public string ImgPath
    {
        get
        {
            return _ImgPath;
        }
        set
        {
            _ImgPath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImgPath");
        }
    }

    private ICommand _mouseMoveCommand;
    public ICommand MouseMoveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mouseMoveCommand == null)
            {
              _mouseMoveCommand = new RelayCommand(param => ExecuteMouseMove((MouseEventArgs)param));
            }      
            return _mouseMoveCommand;
        }
        set { _mouseMoveCommand = value; }
    }
    private void ExecuteMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Point p = e.GetPosition(((IInputElement)e.Source));
        XY = String.Format("X: {0} Y:{1}", (int)p.X, (int)p.Y);

        BitmapData bd = Img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Img.Width, Img.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        unsafe
        {
            byte* ptr = (byte*)bd.Scan0;
            int x = (int)p.X * 3;
            int y = (int)p.Y * bd.Stride;
            RGB = "R: "+ptr[x + y + 2].ToString() + " G: " + ptr[x + y + 1].ToString() + " B: " + ptr[x + y].ToString();
        }
        Img.UnlockBits(bd);
    }
    private string xy;
    public string XY
    {
        get { return xy; }
        set
        {
            xy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("XY");
        }
    }
    private string rgb;
    public string RGB
    {
        get { return rgb; }
        set
        {
            rgb = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RGB");
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Menu FontSize="20">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding OpenImg}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="LightGray">
        <Viewbox Margin="3,3,3,3">
                    <Image x:Name="img" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding ImgPath}"
                           Model:MouseBehaviour.MouseMoveCommand="{Binding MouseMoveCommand}">     
                    </Image>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Focusable="False" Text="{Binding XY}" Width="100"/>
            <TextBox Focusable="False" Text="{Binding RGB}" Width="115"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Model:MouseBehaviour is missing in your sample